# Merge files with awk

Tags: awk

I am attempting to merge `file1` and `file2` based on the number in column2 from `file2` and the number in column1 from `file1` delimited mainly by a comma. There is also a `.` delimiter between the number I am trying to match in `file2`

Here is file 1.

```
1,Mary,24 Fuller Rd
2,Fred,19 St Johns
3,Jonathan,8 Poplar Drive
4,Susan,116 Shepherds Way
5,Michael,4 Nerthern Court
```

and file 2

```
Dawning,Order.5.DHL
Hawkins,Order.3.FedEx
Jacob,Order.2.Yodel
Plateu,Order.4.DPD
Martins,Order.1.Hermes
```

My approach is to extract the key from `file2` with `split`. As a single file, this works, but when working with multiple files, the behaviour is weird and not the expected results.

```
awk -F, '{{split($2,i,".")}{ print i[2]}' file2
5
3
2
4
1
```

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{split($2,i,"."); next}{ print i[2]}' file2 file1
1
1
1
1
1
```

I only get the expected result if I remove `split` but then have no way of extracting the match.

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{array[$2]}END{ for (i in array) print i}' file2 file1
Order.4.DPD
Order.3.FedEx
Order.1.Hermes
Order.5.DHL
Order.2.Yodel
```

There are many other steps i have taken and failed at but it may make the question overly bloated so if more information regarding this is needed, please ask.

My expected result would look like this

```
Mary Martins 24 Fuller Rd
Fred Jacob 19 St Johns
Jonathan Hawkins 8 Poplar Drive
Susan Plateu 116 Shepherds Way
Michael Dawning 4 Nerthern Court
```

Where column2 from `file2` and column1 in `file1` match based on the number therefore printing `$2` and `$NF` from `file1` and `$1` from `file2`

Here are a few of my failed attempts amongst many

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {M=$1; array[$2]; next}{($1 in array)}END{ for (i in array) print $2, M, $NF}' file2 file1
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {M=$1; array[$2]; for (i in array) split(i,a,"."); next} $1==a[2]{print $2,M, $3}' file2 file1
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {M=$1; array[$2]; next}END { for (i in array) split(i,a,".")}($1~a[2]){ print $2,M}' file2 file1
```

I have included the `perl` tag as I'd be interested in solutions with `perl` but primarily want to do this with `awk` if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that file1 and your expected output doesn't match for the first row, perhaps a typo `Fuller Road`? Also, it would be better to group input and expected output together instead of needing too many scrolls to understand the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sh
$ awk -F'[.,]' 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$1; next} {print $2, a[$1], $3}' file2 FS=, file1
Mary Martins 24 Fuller Road
Fred Jacob 19 St Johns
Jonathan Hawkins 8 Poplar Drive
Susan Plateu 116 Shepherds Way
Michael Dawning 4 Nerthern Court
```

- `-F'[.,]'` use `.` or `,` as field separator for `file2`
- `NR==FNR{a[$3]=$1; next}` save first field of `file2` based on third field as key
- `FS=,` before `file1` in the argument list will change field separator to `,` for `file1`
- `print $2, a[$1], $3` print required data (default `OFS` is single space character)

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -F'[.,]' -ane '$ARGV eq "file2" ? $r{$F[2]} = $F[0] : print "$F[1] $r{$F[0]} $F[2]"' file2 file1
```

- `-F'[.,]'` use `.` or `,` as field separator for `file2` and `file1`
- on `file2`, `$F[0]` = *last name*, `$F[2]` = *id that we want to corelate with file1 id*
- on `file1`, `$F[0]` = *id*, `$F[1]` = *first name*, `$F[2]` = *address*
- `-ane` is for while looping / iterating line and autospliting `$_` to `@F` in given files on the command line
- this example use ternary operator in Perl which look like `CONDITION ? EVALUATE_IF_CONDITION_WAS_TRUE : EVALUATE_IF_CONDITION_WAS_FALSE`
- `$ARGV` Contains the name of the current file when reading the line
- `$ARGV eq "file2"` - this is the CONDITION
- if the line read from `"file2"` is true then we store the id as the key and last name as the value into Perl hash (`$r`)
- once the line finished on `file2`, the condition will be false because `$ARGV` will be `'file1'`
- since we already have the `file2` mapping in `$r`, we can get the last name using `$r{$F[0]}`

Comment: you can try -ane option for older perl version